# Combine Multiple Regex Groups in one Regex

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I m trying to combine multiple regex pattern groups into a single regex pattern

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/qK1sA5/36)

```
\b 
(?<CASE_UPPER>[[:upper:]]+)
(?<CASE_MIXED>[A-z]*[A-Z][A-z]*+)
(?<CASE_INITIALCAPS>[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z]*+)
(?<PHRASE>[A-Z][\w-]*\s+[A-Z][\w-]*+)
\b
```

For This Text block:

> I am testing to see if this works for UPPERCASE, InitialCase and mixedCase which of course is also mIxedcase. Firstword initial case should not be matched.  FirstWordMixed case should be. UPPERCASE first word should be. And of course phrases that combine any combination of UPPER mixEd Initicase should be pulled as a phrase not a word which could be of course Initcase1 Initcase2 Initcase3.  Finally it needs to match all sorto of Associations such as Association of First Words, Last Word for Association, Middle Word Association for Words.

It works with Single group but not working with all together.I don't know if I m doing it in a right way! Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[A-z]` won't do the job you expected.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can you pls correct me?

Comment: to match both upper and lowercase letters `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Are you talking about CASE_MIXED?

Comment: what are you trying to match?

Comment: I m trying to match UPPERCASE, MixedCase, Initialcaps, and phrases all together in one regex. I m able to match it with individual regex pattern. i.e. `(?<CASE_UPPER>[[:upper:]]+)` is matching all UPPERCASES if I remove all other regex patterns. Check this for Initcaps :https://regex101.com/r/qK1sA5/33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understood

You can use alternations `|` to combine the different regex

```
\b 
((?<CASE_UPPER>[[:upper:]]+)|
(?<CASE_INITIALCAPS>[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z]*+)|
(?<CASE_MIXED>[A-z]*[A-Z][A-z]*+)|
(?<PHRASE>[A-Z][\w-]*(\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+))
\b
```

[**Regex Example**](https://regex101.com/r/qK1sA5/39)

Comment: Yes you got my point..I have already tried this..But it doesn't seems to be work with Initialcaps and Phrases

Comment: CASE_INITIALCAPS and PHRASE are missing..Initialcase should work like:https://regex101.com/r/qK1sA5/33

Comment: Your solution worked when I edit to :https://regex101.com/r/qK1sA5/38  but `Initcase1 Initcase2 Initcase3` should be detected as one Phrase.  Currently its detecting only `Initcase1 Initcase2`. It would be great if you can give me a hint how to get it..

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I match CASE_INITIALCAPS after First  occurrence onwards? Because `Firstword Initial Case should not be matched.`

Comment: @VickyGonsalves sorry but i didnt get you

Comment: I mean `Firstword Initial Case should not be matched.` From this phrase only `Initial` should get match by CASE_INITIALCAPS And not the `Firstword`. is it possible?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves But this case is not caugth by `CASE_INITIALCAPS` but by the `PHRASE` I dont think we could distinguish both based on regex